# How to avoid the Runtime Exception error when multiple device ids are inserted at the same time in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, sql-insert, apache-iotdb, iotdb

During the process of batch storage into Apache IoTDB, the following error is occasionally reported, and there is no abnormality in the data inserted. I have verified the data, and found that if two device ids are put together and submitted, this error will be reported; if the device ids are separated or modified, this error will not be reported.

Does anyone know how to avoid this error when submitting multiple device ids?

Data:

```
{"batVol":112,"deviceid":"d111353044124717","ts":1673507471101},
{"batVol":113,"deviceid":"d111116052088933","ts":1673479276302}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.iotdb.rpc.StatementExecutionException: 301: [EXECUTE_STATEMENT_ERROR(301)] Exception occurred: insertStringRecords failed. Index: 0, Size: 0
```